# Ball flies away

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

on my pool game, the white ball jumps and flies over the other balls.
How can I avoid the moving on Z axis?
It's Rigid Body and Shape Sphere

[image]

I tried to lock the Z axis on "Location" but this was not helpful.

Comment: hello maybe share your file (only the uselul objects)?

Comment: @moonboots the file is 1GB...but you can download it here: https://playgroundstudios.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/Projekte/ER_V9zGLD0BOmYPFRf5m9PABY_4Rg6RcciV0Zt6cFe_dgg?e=XDXjCb

Comment: Hello, can't you just share the plane, the stick and the ball?

Comment: @moonboots it's now only the plane, stick and balls but the same file size...(and same link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into the file and found something that stopped it from flying.

The table rigid body setting had it's ***Collision Shape*** as *"Mesh"* I tried fiddling around, and setting the shape to *"Convex Hull"* stopped the ball from flying off.

However as you can see at the end, it still clips through the corner which I can't seem to fix myself. But I hope this helps.

[image: The animation]